# Put 1*2 and 1*3 tiles into a n*m floor as many as possible

Tags: algorithm

Tiles can rotate.

Example:

Given two 1*2 tiles and one 1*3 tile, and the floor is 3*3, we put all of the tiles into the floor as follows:

```
AAA
..B
CCB
```

Now, given n*m floor and p 1*2 tiles and q 1*3 tiles(the number of tiles is limited). Return the maximum number of the tiles that can be put into the floor. For the example, the answer is 3(You can put 3 tiles into the floor).

Comment: Are all floor tiles available to be covered?  Or are certain floor tiles off-limits at the beginning?

Comment: Sounds like 2D-packing to me. This [nice article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu) looks like it could help you.

Comment: Yes. Every grid of floor can be covered(if you can).

Comment: @G.Bach not really. It's a specific problem and may have nice solution.

Comment: @Dukeling You should post that as an answer. Sounds optimal enough to me.

Comment: How are a & b chosen?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that every floor 2x2 or greater can be completely covered, given an unrestricted supply of tiles.  The complexity would be if you want to minimize or maximize the number of tiles used, and/or if the number of tiles of each size is restricted.

Comment: @HotLicks Really? When it comes to 5*5 and all tiles is 1*3?

Comment: @Sayakiss - "given an unrestricted supply of tile

Comment: @HotLicks I can solve it with an unrestricted supply of tile...

Comment: Why answer isn't 4 here?

Comment: @Nakilon Because you only have 3 tiles (2 1x2 and 1 1x3).

Comment: The answer is 42.  Now what is the question?

Comment: You can build a ZDD for the constraints (non-overlapping, cover all places, don't go outside the floor) and then get the maximum satisfying assignment. Not sure how well this scales, but I've used this technique to solve Project Euler problems that looked a bit like this.

Comment: @harold What is ZDD? please give me more information about ZDD

Comment: @Dielogik there's a short explanation here: http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/zdd/  and more in-depth info in The Art of Computer Programming 7.1.4 (volume 4A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of Dukeling is wrong. Considering a 5*5 floor and 8 1*3 tiles. The only way to put all of the tiles into the floor is:

```
AAACD
BBBCD
EF.CD
EFGGG
EFHHH
```

And that can't be achieved by replacement.

Then how to do it? I have done a lot of math works and know it well. I will give you some hint:

1. Put 1*3 tiles first and put 1*3 in such a way that we can put the 1*2 as many as possible(Actually, assume there is n uncovered tiles of the floor, in such a way we can put floor(n/2) 1*2 tiles).
2. Be careful with some corner cases. For example, all tiles is 1*3, floor is 1*10, and floor is 2*10 etc.

If you have any problem, leave me a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure that Dukeling's solution is wrong. If we don't want to use parallel 2*1 tiles, or we simply don't care about the rotations, only the size, the result will be correct. At your sample, we can put down 12 1*2 tiles, then we can replace them by 8 3*1 ones(If we look only the size). I dont have a proof, but I cann't find a counterexample.

Comment: If you only care the size, your solution is the same as his

Comment: I wouldn't quite say it is wrong. I did say `"there may be some additional complexities"`. You just pointed out that one such complexity is the above case, where we don't have any 1x2 tiles, and presumably also some cases where we have very few 1x2 tiles.

Answer (score 4):

There may be some additional complexities, but here's my idea:

- Fill the entire floor with 1x2 tiles. It should be simple enough to do, just ensure that it mainly consists of parallel tiles, something like this: (black and white are both tiles)

  [image: Grid]

  Notice I just filled the bottom row with horizontal tiles rather than vertical, this is just to fill up the grid. And the bottom left tile is empty (you may want to replace the tile right of it with a 1x3 tile).
- If you don't have that many 1x2 tiles, still fill the grid completely, they will be removed in the next step.
- While you don't have enough 1x2 tiles to place, systematically replace 3 parallel 1x2 tiles with 2 1x3 tiles. So:

  [image: Two] becomes [image: Three]

Comment: Great answer and pictures! I think it will work in the special case too, when the floor is 1*n, or there is a row which is not can be covered by parallel 2*1 tiles. In this case 3 continous 2*1 tile will be replaced with 2 3*1 ones. So, in general, maybe there's no need to check if the 3 2*1 tiles are parallel or not.

Comment: and after all, we should check the remaining space on the floor. In the case of 1*9 floor and given 0 1*2 and 3 1*3 tile, after replacing, there will be an additional place for a tile of 1*3

Comment: This can probably be turned into a formula, if anyone feels up to trying to figure that out...

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what to return. Do you need a solution set or only the maximum number?
One simple solution might only use 1*2 tiles. Obviously there might fit more 1*2 tiles then 1*3 tiles.

Assumption `b=0`

```
a = n * m div (1*2)
```

Assumption `a=0`, `m>=3`, `n>=3`

```
b = n * m div (1*3)
```